# Error al actualizar referencia a servicio web

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice

¿Alguien podría decirme por qué me sale el siguiente error al actualizar la referencia a un servicio web?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pones la url en el browser puede observar la pagina por defecto que muestra el servicio web ? podrias intentar accederlo sin que sea https, porque la conexion segura parece que no resuelve

Comment: Si pongo la url me dice "Internet Explorer no puede mostrar la página web" y poniendo solo http (sin la "S"), el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Entonces el servicio web no está funcionando. En el explorador debería funcionarte primeramente

Comment: Consulte la URI del servicio; es posible que esté mal escrita/configurada. Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2164771/4092887) para obtener mas detalles sobre el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es debido al proxy que tienes instalado en el equipo, es decir no llegas al servicio web debido a este filtro, prueba colocando otro proxy o quizás la ruta esté considerada como excepción en el proxy.

Saludos!